# How to make Windows Vista taskbar to appear immediately?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, taskbar, user-experience

I have set to keep taskbar hidden. When I move mouse to screen edge, it appears. But it is slow for me:) I would like to make it to appear immediately. Any ideas?

EDIT: Only what I found is to disable menu animation in visual effects settings.

Comment: faster computer? :)

Comment: It will not help, since the animation is time driven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [tweaking the registry](http://wingeek.com/articles/39445/adjust-taskbar-preview-hover-delay/) ? Apparently, this delay seems to be defined by `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\MouseHoverTime`